# What is the best way to communicate between programs in .NET and why?

Tags: .net, web-services, api, communication, dll

Our company keeps debating on whether we should be using custom API DLLs or creating a web service farm to have our programs to communicate data between themselves. To me web services make the most sense in regards to compatibility and flexibility of upgrading, but I have heard some good reasons to use DLLs as well.

Is there an emerging preference for .NET applications, or a choice that you have found that works best? And if so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: There is probably no "best" way. This question is too broad to give a good answer. There are so many ways to realize inter-process communication, many having specific advantages for a certain setup/use-case so that it is difficult to make a general statement.

Comment: You ought to tell us what sort of applications they are, why they are communicating, what sort of data they are sending and the volume of messages sent. Or as divo says the answer will be pretty meaningless.

Comment: Pretty much all are VB.NET code (sigh), some ASP.Net programs and some VB6 programs. Mainly the communication is needed to retrieve information from each application for what it stores, such as weather, market prices, customer information, invoicing.

It sounds like web services have problems with large sets of data... which makes me think that for the large volume of market prices that we transfer... API Dlls might be the way to go from what I am reading below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's pros & cons of each - if you'll always be running .net apps then you could arguably get better performance from the dll approach.  Remoting can work well too.

For greater long term flexibility that will allow you to easily integrate with other platforms  & internal/external clients should the need arise you could look at building RESTful web service APIs to your applications.

In some circumstances I've worked at places that did intra-app communication in the data tier via some well crafted stored procedures which worked perfectly in that scenario.

I always consider the tools that best fit the task at hand rather than trying to fit in with any specific trends, however, if your doing anything that could involve external client interaction I'd definitely look at whether there are published communications standards already in place that you can pick up - there's a lot of standards out there that you can employ to aid interoperability within your industry.

Answer (score 9):

I guess I would say WCF. The reasons are manifold:

1. Tested/Trusted codebase. Why recreate the wheel?
2. Functionality. Anything you can do WCF can do better. WCF can do anything better than you. Seriously though, you can do secure messaging with certs or windows or whatever you want. You can make the binding xml-based or binary. You can make your application layer redundant using Addressing. There's really nothing you can't do with WCF.
3. Less coding!!! Less money!!
4. Support. There's a bunch of books and knowledge about WCF out there on the web.

In the old days, remoting was da-bomb because web services couldn't really do stuff like Security etc, without having to know WS-*, which was daunting. Not true now with WCF. Yes there is a learning curve that comes with it, but you'd be learning something that can transfer to any other Microsoft shop.

Just make sure you read up on the right way to do WCF. For example, seperate all of your messaging stuff into it's own seperate DLL.

Comment: I don't think that WCF is compatible with all of his environments, but you couldn't have known that when you wrote your answer.

Answer (score 5):

DLLs or assemblies by themselves do not resolve the communication issue between programs.  However, when building assemblies in the past, what I have done is utilize a shared memory space, which the custom dll uses to access shared objects across applications.  I've done this for applications that have an accompanied Outlook add-in and it has been quite successful.

The pros to that approach is that it will be faster than using the web services route.

However, I think this really boils down to your situation, because I could see using multiple venues for different circumstances.

Shared Memory/Web Services/Remoting/WCF, just to name a few.

Answer (score 4):

We use a mixture of things, mostly depending on where they get deployed, who is the "customer" and who are the "threats." We mostly use webservices for things that desktop applications touch, but for the parts of the server-based application that need to talk to each other, we use remoting (because that doesn't get routed past the load balancers, while a webservice would be visible to everyone).

Comment: Why would a web service be visible to everyone?

Comment: unless you've changed some sort of configuration on your web server, all web services are visible on ports 80 and 443. Ports that are open by intention on virtuallty every router, firewall and load balancer. Remoting lets you pick your own port, and most folks pick things that are unroutable out on the internet. Once you've guessed the endpoint of the web service, the vast majority are set to display a WSDL when you append ?WSDL to the web service. And that gives hackers a blueprint for action. There are ways around it, but there isn't enough room to give them here in a single comment.

Answer (score 3):

All .net/MS shops usually do process communications with web services since microsoft makes that relatively easy.

The only problem I've found with it in practice is we once had a production failure due to a limit on the size of a passed message. It defaulted to a megabyte and a very large serialized object failed to fit in that space. It used serialization to text instead of binary.

In our setup it was all internal for an SOA architecture and we didn't have to worry about threats.

Answer (score 3):

As most of the other posters have pointed out, it's difficult to provide advice without some more specifics.

If your requirements allow for asynchronous messaging, you might want to consider using [System.Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.aspx) in conjunction with [Message Queue](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx) as a third option.

Answer (score 2):

For our application, we chose a mix.  We use web services to go across the internet to allow for load balancing and 3rd party development but use tcpchannel remoting to allow for fast communication between servers.  It depends upon the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the processes are one separate machines, your choices are mainly web services/WCF, .NET remoting or a direct TCP/IP connection.  If the processes are on the same machine you have those choices and more, including shared memory and the filesystem.  .NET remoting deserves a close look if you don't need to interop with any other technologies - it doesn't need codegen to do its work and so is simpler with decent performance.

Answer (score 2):

WCF really is the way to go here--write the service, let configuration decide the transport medium.

In terms of picking transport mediums, alot of really has to do with your network architecture and requirements. Http is great for remote stuff and getting through firewalls but bloody inefficient whereas Tcp can be fast but unreliable.